# Better understanding DyamoDB compound sort keys

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, nosql, dynamodb-queries

I'm trying to understand how use compound sort keys as discussed in [this video.](https://youtu.be/T6VZ_GfQdvo?t=491) I understand the concept of chaining values together in this key to make querying for data more efficient, but I don't understand implementing it yet in the context of an application.

Let's say I'm building a database for a mechanic shop. The DB is mainly concerned with three models: `driver`, `car`, and `document`. A `driver` can have many `cars` and many `documents`, but a given `car` or `document` can only be associated with a single `driver`.

My first pass schema:

```
driver partition key: driver_id

car partition key: driver_id
car sort key: car_id

document partition key: driver_id
document sort key: document_id
```

I'm able to retrieve all cars and all documents owned by a single driver. However, let's say on the frontend side of my application I want to display a list of all drivers currently in the database, as well as a box that's ticked if that driver has submitted their documents and another box that's ticked if that driver's car has been registered. I can query both the `car` and `document` tables for every single driver to check if associated records exist for them. If this mechanic has a backlog of thousands of customers, this is untenable.

I should be able to create a sort key for the `driver` table that, when querying a specific driver, will also return all cars and all documents associated with them.

Am I correct, and if so, is this the proper method to approach a problem like this with?

Where is documentation?

I found [this section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/WorkingWithItemCollections.html) of the AWS documentation, but it hasn't been much help.

Comment: I think you may have missed the broader point here. You would use (what you're calling) 'composite sort keys' in a single table design. You've proposed multiple tables, so the concept of composite sort keys isn't relevant. Imagine a single table where the pk=driver_id (or possibly driver#driver_id) and the sk is either car#car_id or doc#document_id.

Comment: One question: you need to check a box if "that driver's car has been registered". What does this actually relate to? The presence of 1+ cars for the given driver ID?

Comment: @jarmod Yes exactly. Basically if one or more cars exist in the DB associated with a given driver_id, that box is checked. Same concept for the document checkbox.

Per your other reply: Is the solution then to store all of the drivers/cars/documents together on a single table to be able to make use of sort keys in this way? Or is there a method I can take advantage of while operating with the original multiple tables solution to achieve this? 

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The benefit of single table design, assuming it's appropriate, is that you can answer most/all of your questions with a single query. If you had multiple tables, you wouldn't be able to do that.

Comment: Couple of examples. Find cars for a given driver: query pk=driver_id, sk begins_with "car#". Find all cars and docs for a given driver: query pk=driver_id.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Put all & only what is needed to ask in your post, not at a link, Quote with credit & relate to your post. Don't expect us tor read linked content & guess what is relevant & why. Asking for off-site resources is off-topic. Yes or no questions are seldom helpful & seldom asking for what is actually wanted. PS A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" not summarizing a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly" or "falsely". [ask] [Help] [mre]

Comment: @philipxy No expectation to watch anything, it was just there to provide further context for anyone curious. The question I posted was self contained and produced the answer I was looking for. Thanks for your time.

Comment: You don't explain "how use compound sort keys as discussed", "implementing it", etc. If that paragraph is not needed, it is noise & doesn't belong. PS Your post does not contain a clear phasing of a question. Parts of the sentences that end in question marks refer back to the entire preceding post. (Etc.)

Answer (score 2):

The issue with your design is that you are relying on 3 tables, when you actually only need one. The idea behind DynamoDB's data modelling, is data that you want to access together, should live together on the same table.

| pk | sk | type | data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| driverId | driver#driverId | driver | some data |
| driverId | document#documentId | document | some data |
| driverId | document#documentId | document | some data |
| driverId | car#carId | car | some data |
| driverId | car#carId | car | some data |

See the above table, I have defined a relationship between all items. A given driver has one to many documents/cars.

Now when I want to load my front-end application for a given driver, I do so using DynamoDB `Query` which would look like the following in SQL terms:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK=driverId`

No if my access pattern was to only get the driver information, I could do a `GetItem`, which would look like this in SQL:

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE PK=driverId AND SK=driver#driverId`

Comment: I see, this makes a lot of sense. On a conceptual level, is there any instance in which you'd want to spread your data cross several tables when working with DynamoDB? Or is it build to be used specifically with a single table design like this?

Comment: And as a follow up question, when initially creating the table that you've described above, what value would I actually supply to the Sort Key field being that different data types on the table will have different sort keys?

Comment: @ZachKaigler Please ask a (single clear specific researched non-duplicate) further question in a new question post, comments are not for that. If you want a different answer for your question post then edit it to ask the (single ...) question that you actually want an answer to. (But don't edit in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers.)

Comment: The sk would be string type. The prefix would be a string such as "car#" and the suffix would be a stringized resource identifier.

Comment: As @jarmod states, use a string. As for the number of tables, as I stated in the answer you tend to always store related data together. The idea is to denormalize the data so you can read all you want in a single request, there are no joins.